# Do Lucene's analyzers create a tf-idf representation?

Tags: lucene, indexing

I'd like to know if Lucene's analyzers use the tf-idf representation ofr building the index.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it does. That's a major factor when calculating scoring (similarity). Look [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) for more info.

Comment: But, if it does it by default, I don't understand why they do this: http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/12/30/how-to-easily-build-and-observe-tf-idf-weight-vectors-with-lucene-and-mahout/

Comment: Well, `TF-IDF` is not the same thing as `TF-IDF Weight Vector`. See [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/10552567/TFIDF) for more info about tf/idf/wv.

Answer (score 2):

No: Analyzers just break a document into a stream of tokens.

IndexWriter is an analysis consumer that builds an inverted index, recording raw statistics like how many occurrences of the term appear in the document and how many documents contain the term.

But this isnt a tf/idf representation: the index format is independent of the scoring model.

Comment: @Kits89, but you meant to ask about the whole indexing process, not just analyzers, (which is obvious if you follow the link you mentioned in your comment). Right?

Comment: I mean, when you create an index with Lucene, it finds the most probable words in each document and associates a number to assess how important are... right? that is a tf-idf model, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, indexing doesnt create a TF/IDF representation. Again the index format is independent of the scoring model. This is why lucene is able to implement other scoring models in 4.0